In the TNG episode "lower decks", who had the conn after the order was given to divert to the Argaya system?
After the battle drill, Picard directly orders helm to change course. The senior officers (Picard, Riker, Worf and Data) all then leave for a briefing at the same time.
Nobody is ordered to "take the conn", and there don't appear to be any Command officers present, so who inherited it at that point?

You've asked about this sort of scenario before, and received answers: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/275411/122024

@OrangeDog - In this instance it's asking about a specific instance when command wasn't transferred and there doesn't appear to be a senior officer present

I disagree that this is a dupe. The other question is asking about the transfer of the conn when there are command officers present. This one is asking about a situation where all the command officers got up and left.

Unusually, when Riker and Picard leave the bridge in this episode there doesn't appear to be another senior office present, only lower-ranked officers jockeying for the various console positions.
The episode script is very clear that Data's seat (at Ops) needs to be directly manned at all times, but the fact that nobody is eyeing up the big chair indicates that nobody present is expecting a change of Conn just because Captain Picard is going into the Observation lounge for a few minutes.

PICARD: I've just received new orders from Starfleet. We'll discuss it in the Observation Lounge.
Data stands to join Picard and Worf as they cross toward the Observation Lounge. Lavelle looks over at Data's vacant chair -- someone is going to have to man Ops and he hopes he is chosen. Riker glances at him, then back toward Sito.
RIKER: Ensign Sito, you'll fill in at Ops.

So who the heck is in charge!?
It would appear that Picard remains in charge, despite formally having left the Bridge. He's only in the next room over, separated by a short corridor. In the event that something happens we can reasonably expect that someone will take the ten-second walk to the Observation Lounge and say

"Er, Captain, we're detected a swirly thing, dead ahead. It seems to be spewing anti-anti-protons."

and he'll walk back into the room.

Somehow I expected that second link to be the "who's flying this thing!?" scene from Firefly.

@Cadence - Damn it, that would have been a better joke.
